# Help simplifying this sum $f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n} e^{-x^2/n} 2^{-n}$, $ x \ge 0$

Tags: summation, self-learning

I am stuck on this sum

$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n} e^{-x^2/n} 2^{-n}$ $ x \ge 0$

Any tips on how to get started?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a fruitful start. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
notice that
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2x}{n} e^{-x^2/n} 2^{-n}
  \\ &= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} {d\over dx} e^{-x^2/n}
  \\ &= -F'(x)
\end{align}$$
where
$$ F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} e^{-x^2/n} $$
is absolutely convergent since each term is bounded
above by $2^{-n}$ (and below by $2^{-n}e^{-x^2}$).
In fact, it follows that $e^{-x^2}\le F(x)\le 1$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, with equality iff $x=0$.
The absolute convergence of $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$
allows us to differentiate term by term and bestows
the same infinite radius of convergence on $f=-F'$.

The function $F$ is similar to a "mixed" distribution,
a sum of Gaussian or normal distributions
all centered at the origin,
but with linearly increasing variance
and geometrically decreasing weight.
However the normalizing constants
$(\pi n)^{-\frac12}$ are absent,
(and the $x$-axis is contracted by the factor $\sqrt2$)
so that the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty F(x)dx
=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\sqrt{n}\over2^n}.
$$
What was your goal? To prove that $f(x)$ converges, find its
radius of convergence, or find an analytic formula for its sum?